# Different permissions when navigating to a remote server folder via UNC path w/ Explorer than when I remote in via Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, security, network-shares

Here at work, we connect to remote servers when we need to deploy our production code.  I often use Windows Explorer to navigate to a server folder directly via UNC path to delete, rename, or copy files.  Of the five servers, one server has one folder that won't allow me to do any of those actions.  It tells me `You need permission to perform this action`.  However, I can remote into the server using Remote Desktop and manipulate files from that folder all day long.  Oddly, I can access other folders on that server via Windows Explorer and manipulate files without a problem.  It's just that one folder that's giving me problems.

Is this something I can change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that might cause that is if the permissions on the sharing tab are set to read only but the security tab has it set to read write. This would mean that when you access the folder via the share using UNC it would be read only but when you accessed it directly on the drive it would be read write.

This would affect every folder in the share though.

Answer (score 0):

I think Col's suggestion of share vs. folder permissions is probably dead-on.  Otherwise, another thing to look into is that there may be specific machine-level denies on the share/folder, which can override you user-level credentials.